# Get attr tag with preg_match_all that contains a text

Tags: php, preg-match-all

how can I get the ALT attribute within a text string with an image, with this function I get the src, but I also want to get the alt

```
<?php 
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img alt='my alt text' src='1.jpg' />  consectetur adipiscing elit, blandit quis aliquam integer neque turpis vel, ullamcorper nunc erat potenti dui vitae. Nunc tristique habitasse convallis congue praesent ultricies nam imperdiet netus, eleifend libero velit per maecenas sagittis vestibulum rhoncus felis tortor, etiam duis at sem dictumst vulputate nisi dignissim. Pharetra condimentum ultrices eleifend potenti eget blandit tempus dui class lectus magna vehicula, fames a ad ac commodo pulvinar aliquet augue semper venenatis massa, litora nascetur nam arcu et diam nec varius sollicitudin eu tristique."
preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $text, $matches);
$src = $matches[1][0]; // get attr 'src'
```

But I also want ALT, how can I do it with a similar expression?

Comment: You would be better off using something like DOMDocument and loadHTML as it understands the structure and context of HTML tags and attributes.  Using regexes is always open to mistakes and to much restriction on the document flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your asking:

```
   $text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img alt='my alt text' src='1.jpg' />  consectetur adipiscing elit, blandit quis aliquam integer neque turpis vel, ullamcorper nunc erat potenti dui vitae. Nunc tristique habitasse convallis congue praesent ultricies nam imperdiet netus, eleifend libero velit per maecenas sagittis vestibulum rhoncus felis tortor, etiam duis at sem dictumst vulputate nisi dignissim. Pharetra condimentum ultrices eleifend potenti eget blandit tempus dui class lectus magna vehicula, fames a ad ac commodo pulvinar aliquet augue semper venenatis massa, litora nascetur nam arcu et diam nec varius sollicitudin eu tristique.";

// array of attributes
$attr = [];

// src attribute
   preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $text, $matches);
   array_push($attr, $matches[1][0]);

// alt attribute
   preg_match_all('/<img.+?alt=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $text, $matches);
   array_push($attr, $matches[1][0]);

// result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to capture alt and src

```
<?php
$re = '/<img.*?alt=\'(.*?)\' src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/m';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img alt=\'my alt text\' src=\'1.jpg\' />  consectetur adipiscing elit, blandit quis aliquam integer neque turpis vel, ullamcorper nunc erat potenti dui vitae. Nunc tristique habitasse convallis congue praesent ultricies nam imperdiet netus, eleifend libero velit per maecenas sagittis vestibulum rhoncus felis tortor, etiam duis at sem dictumst vulputate nisi dignissim. Pharetra condimentum ultrices eleifend potenti eget blandit tempus dui class lectus magna vehicula, fames a ad ac commodo pulvinar aliquet augue semper venenatis massa, litora nascetur nam arcu et diam nec varius sollicitudin eu tristique."
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);

?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FK3nd

Comment: My content didn't have the character  `\'`, so that's why I didn't always grab the attributes well.

Comment: Then make it optional by appending a `? ` after it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant with placeholder which i find it makes it easier to process the results with:

```php
$re = '/(<img.*alt=\'(?<alt>.*)\'|src=\'(?<src>.*)\'.*\/>)/mU';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img alt=\'my alt text\' src=\'1.jpg\' />  consectetur adipiscing elit, blandit quis aliquam integer neque turpis vel, ullamcorper nunc erat potenti dui vitae. Nunc tristique habitasse convallis congue praesent ultricies nam imperdiet netus, eleifend libero velit per maecenas sagittis vestibulum rhoncus felis tortor, etiam duis at sem dictumst vulputate nisi dignissim. Pharetra condimentum ultrices eleifend potenti eget blandit tempus dui class lectus magna vehicula, fames a ad ac commodo pulvinar aliquet augue semper venenatis massa, litora nascetur nam arcu et diam nec varius sollicitudin eu tristique.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

And the results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "<img alt='my alt text'"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "<img alt='my alt text'"
    ["alt"]=>
    string(11) "my alt text"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "my alt text"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "src='1.jpg' />"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "src='1.jpg' />"
    ["alt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["src"]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: My content didn't have the character  `\'`, so that's why I didn't always grab the attributes well.